# $.on() bubbling after stopPropagation();

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use `.on()` to tell me what i clicked on inside of a region. To capture the exact element I clicked on, I'm calling `event.stopPropagation()` to keep it from bubbling but my output is always `#containerDiv` and its contents.

How can I see exactly what was clicked on within `#containerDiv`? A code snippet is below:

```
$("#containerDiv").on("click",function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `event.target`, not `$(this)`; the latter will always be the element to which the handler was assigned.

Comment: @jfriend00: I believe that only applies for delegated events; this case is not one.

Comment: Downvote rescinded.  Yes, that is true.  It applies to delegated events.  The OP appears like they want to use delegated event handling, but they are doing it the manual way.  They could just put the selector for the actual object as a `.on()` argument and then they won't have to manually use `event.target`.

Comment: @jfriend00: That's true. I should have known there wasn't enough jQuery in my answer. `;)`

Answer (score 5):

When you capture the event on the container, the event has *already bubbled.*

Answer (score 2):

Try giving the `on()` method a `selector`:

```
$("#containerDiv").on("click", "*", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SnPjS/2/

Comment: Works! I also found another way to do it. Instead of event.stopPropagation, event.target will return the element that triggered the handler.